# autoDeploy in Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, autodeploy

I have a dev enviornment running Tomcat7 on a FreeBSD server.  I want to make sure no apps auto deploy so I've used the following in my server.xml

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="false">
```

The problem is I still need to have manager and host-manager to auto start.  Is there a way to keep all apps except these from auto deploying?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify deployOnStartup as false, then none of the applications will load , including wars and directories (manager and host-manager).

You'd have to explicitly configure the manager app via a Context element in server.xml and then use that to deploy additional WAR files and/or directories.

`<Context path="/blah" docBase="h:/tmp/mywar.war" reloadable="true" />`

**Edit**

To deploy your manager app , you will have to add the following

```
<Context docBase="/home/msaif/tomcat/6u35/webapps/manager" path="/manager" reloadable="true" privileged="true"></Context>
```

***Dont forget to mark it privileged***